# A more idiomatic way of saying "that had the secret meaning of"

Tags: idiomatic-language

> The Shining was an allegory that had the secret meaning of the
> genocide of Native Americans.

This sounds incorrect.

> The Shining was an allegory about the genocide of Native Americans.

That also sounds incorrect and a bit vague

Is there a better way to say this? I think the last one makes the most sense, but the about doesn't specify if it's the secret meaning conveyed by the allegory or the literal subject of the film.

Comment: The usual expression is _an allegory_ **of** _[something]_.

Comment: "secret meaning" is slightly childish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An allegory, by definition, is a narrative that carries a subtext. Having stated that something is an allegory, there is no need for you to say that it has a "secret meaning" at all. In fact, if the meaning were really a 'secret', it wouldn't be a very good allegory, because nobody would knew what it meant.

Just say:

> The Shining was an allegory of the genocide of Native Americans.